Помогите добавить анимацию popup окну


<section class="u-align-center u-black u-clearfix u-container-align-center u-container-style u-dialog-block u-opacity u-opacity-70 u-dialog-section-12" id="carousel_2200">
  <div class="u-container-style u-dialog u-radius u-shape-round u-white u-dialog-1">
    <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1">
      <img alt="" class="u-expanded-width-xs u-image u-image-round u-radius u-image-1" data-image-width="1280" data-image-height="853" src="images/03b359c6d4f798d6a74b25939dbdabaf29b28fbd9248a51c34a7fdfbd1077257ff1ec5470afdbab1d7598a66e503ed83c0f7e69ffaf03a06d6aa55_1280.jpg"
        data-animation-name="customAnimationIn" data-animation-duration="1000" data-animation-delay="0">
      <div class="u-align-center u-container-align-center u-container-style u-group u-radius u-shape-round u-group-1">
        <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
          <h3 class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-font-playfair-display u-text u-text-palette-5-dark-2 u-text-1">Подайте заявку​ в наш колледж</h3>
          <div class="u-expanded-width u-form u-form-1">
            <form action="надо делать" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-23 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" style="padding: 10px" source="email" name="form">
              <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-form-group-1">
                <label for="name-9cc4" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" id="name-9cc4" name="name" class="u-border-2 u-border-black u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-input u-input-rectangle" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="u-form-email u-form-group u-form-group-2">
                <label for="email-9cc4" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" id="email-9cc4" name="Телефон" class="u-border-2 u-border-black u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-input u-input-rectangle" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="u-align-center u-form-group u-form-submit u-form-group-3">
                <a href="#" class="u-black u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style u-btn-1">Отправить </a>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
              </div>
              <div class="u-form-send-message u-form-send-success"> Отправлено </div>
              <div class="u-form-send-error u-form-send-message"> Не получилось</div>
              <input type="hidden" value="" name="recaptchaResponse">
              <input type="hidden" name="formServices" value="0e536b6a-8a55-e7ce-46e0-09085b59b309">
            </form>
          </div>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В принципе можно использовать Bootstrap 3.
Пример кода на нём:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Открыть PopUP.</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Заголовок PopUP</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Немного текста тут.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть.</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>




пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Фреймворку уж больше 10 лет)
